# How to export different tables from mysql database to different XML file using dbunit?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, gradle, dbunit

I am trying to export a database into XML file using DBUNIT. I am facing problem while generating separate XML for each table. I could not able to do this.
Can someone help me with this?
Following is the code:
  `

```
QueryDataSet partialDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
        addTables(partialDataSet);

// XML file into which data needs to be extracted

        FlatXmlDataSet.write(partialDataSet, new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/name/Desktop/test-dataset_temp.xml"));
        System.out.println("Data set written");
```

```
static private void addTables(QueryDataSet dataSet) {
        if (tableList == null) return;
        for (Iterator k = tableList.iterator(); k.hasNext(); ) {
            String table = (String) k.next();

            try {
                dataSet.addTable(table);

            } catch (AmbiguousTableNameException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }`
```

Now my problem is how to I seperate tables so that I can generate seperate xml file for each table.
Thanks in Advance